# Java OOP functionality between objects

Tags: java, oop

I have a problem with solving exercise

> There are two classes ready in the exercise: ObjectFunctionality and
>   Calculator. Your task is to create the class Printer which asks for
>   two integers from the user, calls the method Sum() of class Calculator
>   relaying the inputted integers to the method. Method Sum() counts the
>   sum of the numbers and returns the result. Finally Sum() prints the
>   sum on screen.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ObjectFunctionality {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Printer thing = new Printer();
        thing.Print();
    }
}

//  Write the missing class here
//  Class is written in the text box below.

class Calculator {
    static int Sum(int first, int second) {
        int sum = first + second;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
class Printer {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type in the first integer: ");
    int first = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Type in the second integer: ");
    int second = reader.nextInt();


    System.out.print("Sum of the numbers: " + sum.sum);


}
```

I know that something is very wrong, but I cant solve this.

PS. I need an output like this:

> Type in the first integer: -3 Type in the second integer: -1 Sum of
>   the numbers: -4

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's your question? It isn't clear what specifically you're asking.

Comment: Poor title. Edit to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
public class Printer {

    void Print(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type in the first integer: ");
        int first = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Type in the second integer: ");
        int second = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Sum of the numbers: ");
        int sum = Calculator.Sum(first, second);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```